# Avoid pausing tasks when select something on PowerShell and Command Prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

When I click and select texts on PowerShell and Command Prompt, running tasks always be paused. How can I avoid this?

I'd like to avoid accidental stopping tasks by unexpected mouse control. ( I just need normal selecting behaviors with no side effects like mac or linux terminal. )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tend to like this feature or maybe I am just use to it. Sometimes it is nice to pause a task.

i hit one of the arrow keys to "unpause" something when I want it to continue.

https://www.vistax64.com/threads/script-pauses-when-you-click-in-the-powershell-text-window.112032/

The only method I know of changing this is the "Quick Edit" setting, via the registry
`HKCU\Console\QuickEdit` `0x1` (on) `0x0` (off)

Or by going to the properties of the console windows (right click on title bar, Properties) to change the setting:

[image]

Comment: Hi Midacts, I was just about to post a similar answer re: Quick Edit, figured I'd just edit yours instead. Just mentioning since you're new here and that might seem weird. If you don't like the edit please free to roll it back via the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60584073/edit) link and I can post separately. Thanks and welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This works well, but a little different from what I needed, selecting behaviors with no side effects like mac or linux terminal. Can't I achieve this with PowerShell?

Comment: If I replace terminal app to ConEmu, I can select texts without pausing. I'd like to achieve this by normal terminal apps on Windows if I can.

Comment: Sorry, I could do select texts without Quick Edit mode, by selecting right-click menu > Mark (or Select All), I'll use this way. And I also understood pause / unpause function is unique and convenient as you said :) Thank you.