# Alternative to cmd and powershell for stdout output only

Tags: windows, command-prompt

## My use case:

[image]

I kick-off a Python script from a button within Excel to do some data aggregation. The setup currently works nicely, but I would like:

- Cmd to never accidentally pause - it's a known *feature* of the command prompt to pause on any text selection: [Avoid pausing tasks when select something on PowerShell and Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583915)
- To let the cmd prompt look more like a pop-up

I have noticed NSIS installers outputs it's commands in a little logging box:

[image]

## Question:

I would like to know if there are any programs out there that does most of what I want already. E.g. something like `RunLikePopup.exe c:\path\to\script.bat`, with output like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are really after.  I 'll give it a try.
In case you build an application as 'console'-only than that results in a 'command-line-interface [CLI]' Look-and-feel. Plane and simple. The output of a NSIS script (.nsi file) can not be paused as it is simply the output of the compiler executing the script code. 'Pausing' that would instantly mean pausing the compiler to do its work. I see no reason why you would want that.

Example Unix 'more' command (sending text oriented content to stdout. CLI...) 
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)

In case you need to 'catch' the output from the NSIS compiler here is what you need to do:
run NSIS from (Windows) CLI:

```
makensis [ option | script.nsi | - ] [...] > compiler_log.txt
```

What you appear to want is typically named 'output redirect'. (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). In case you need to 'catch' the outpout from a NSIS script at compile time, please use NSIS ' CLI and redirect the (compilers) output to any text file (e.g. compiler_output.txt)

PS.  In order to ensure receiving good quality answers, try to be as specific as you can in your questions.

Comment: Thanks @Guybrush_Treepwood, my original question wasn't that clear, so I have edited it with examples of what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Freeware editor ME "Martins Editor" where you can send text via inpipe:

```
[C:\]dir /s | me in
```

"in" always shows the first page (does not scroll), "ins" scrolls and "inp" scrolls page by page. In this context, "me in" is a substitute for "more".

Then you will see the output in the editor. ME is a simple editor with the focus on multiplatform text (different EOL encodings, codepages). It has additional Wordstar ("IDE classic") key setting and HTML/XML highlightning. It is available for Windows, OS/2, Linux and MacOS.

http://www.hypermake.com/english/betatest.html#hd117

The 2016 version is still current. In the next weeks, I publish a new version.

I am working on a cmd.exe window replacement (commandline frontend) "MeShell" based on ME with look-and-feel of a normal commandline window. Because on the lack of a modern comfortable commandline window on the old OS/2 platform which is still alive (http://www.arcanoae.com), I will publish an OS/2 version first. If this version works fine, I will publish a Windows version later. In the context of MeShell, I improve the inpipe functionality of ME which is still buggy and does not support colors in the 2016 version.